# call uiactivityviewcontroller with spritekit/skscene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a share button to social media from within my game to share a highscore. I can't seem to figure it out, and from various other answers, I've arrived at this code (which throws a NSInternalInconsistencyException). Any ideas?

```
let savedScore = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "HighestScore") as! Int
let textToShare = "My highscore on Panda Pong is \(savedScore)! Can you beat that?"

let objectsToShare = [textToShare]
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
                activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList]

let vc = UIViewController(nibName: "testview", bundle: nil) as UIViewController

vc.present(activityVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
let vc = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!

vc.present(activityVC, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Not exactly sure why, but messed around with some syntax and arrived at this answer.

Comment: If you are a good swift developer you do not want to not use ! to make sure you do not crash when vc is nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way in spritekit

```
 ...
 let rootViewController = view?.window?.rootViewController
 rootViewController?.present(activityVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Instead of trying to instantiate a new ViewController just use the rootViewController (GameViewController).

I would also reccomend to not do things such as

```
let savedScore = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "HighestScore") as! Int
```

with force casting the user defaults value (as! Int). You will crash if there is no value yet so change it to this

```
let savedScore = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "HighestScore") as? Int ?? 0
```

You now safely check if the UserDefaults value exists and is an Int (as? Int) and if not it will create a new default value (?? 0).

Furthermore try to put your UserDefaults String keys ("HighestScore") into a constant property so you avoid typos.

```
enum UserDefaultsKey: String {
   case highscore = "HighestScore"
}
```

and than use it like so

```
 UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: UserDefaultsKey.highscore.rawValue)
```

Hope this helps